# Cannot inject mapstruct interface during startup spring application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapstruct

I have the following mapper (mapstruct version 1.3.1.Final).

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {}, unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.WARN)
public interface AccountMapper {
    @Mapping(source = "registrationDto.email", target = "email")
    @Mapping(source = "passwordDto.hashPassword", target = "password")
    Account from(RegistrationDto registrationDto, PasswordDto passwordDto);
}
```

When I attempt to run spring application I got the problem that bean associated with Mapper is not found.

```
Parameter 1 of constructor in com.xx.xx.Controller required a bean of type 'com.xxx.AccountMapper' that could not be found.

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.xxx.AccountMapper' in your configuration.
```

I tried solution with decorator. By adding annotation `@DecoratedWith(AccountMapperDecorator.class)` for interface and creating the following class.

```
@Component
public abstract class AccountMapperDecorator implements AccountMapper {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("delegate")
    private AccountMapper delegate;

    @Override
    public Account from(RegistrationDto registrationDto, PasswordDto passwordDto) {
        return delegate.from(registrationDto, passwordDto);
    }
}
```

And then I receive.

```
No qualifying bean of type 'com.xxx.AccountMapper' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value="delegate")}
```

What could be the problem in that case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you run `mvn package`?
When you search for class `AccountMapperImpl` in your IDE, can you find it? If not that is a problem. If you can't find it, Spring won't too.

Maybe you forgot to configure (or misconfigured) mapstruct-processor in your pom.xml? Do you have something like:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                <version>...</version>
            </path>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

there?

Comment: In your controller, do you autowire the interface or implementation? I mean you autowire AccountMapper or AccountMapperDecorator?

Comment: I'd autowire the interface (`AccountMapper`), the fact that there is some `AccountMapperImpl` or `AccountMapperDecorator` is just implementation detail. But there is no need to create the Decorator manually in this example.

Answer (score 0):

This is a situation that happens from time to time,
If you will noticed then probebly the AccountMapperImpl isn't generated to the `target/build` folders
There a few ways to fix that:

- Try clean the `out/build` directories
- Run `mvn clean compile` or `gradle clean compileJava`
- Set your IDE to run your code with `maven/gradle`
  [image]
- Be sure that `Annotation Processing` is enabled